# Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/functionscdn.azureedge.net - Not found

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-function-app-proxy

npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true --force --trusted-host aunctionscdn.azureedge.net

Hi all, i have been trying to install azure-functions-core tools using above command behind my company proxy, but return this error. need some help on this. much appreciated:

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/functionscdn.azureedge.net - Not found
npm ERR! 404  'functionscdn.azureedge.net@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

regards

Comment: this worked for me `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the registry for specific scopes, if that's the easiest workaround. For example:

```
npm config set @types:registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

That would tell npm to always get anything for the @types scope directly from the official server on the internet. For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/15).